# One-to-Many relationships in (Postgre)SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

posts:

```
 id | ... other stuff ... |     tags                         
----+---------------------+--------------
  1 |         ...         | <foo><bar>
  2 |         ...         | <foo><baz><blah>
  3 |         ...         | <bar><blah><goo>
```

and tags:

```
     tag         
--------------
 <foo>
 <bar>
 <baz>
 <blah>
 <goo>
```

posts.tags and tags.tag are both of type text. What I want is a relation from tags.tag to rows in posts such that querying `<foo>` would give me rows corresponding to posts 1 and 2, querying `<blah>` gives me 2 and 3, `<bar>` gives me 1 and 3, etc.

I've looked at foreign keys, but I'm not sure it's what I want. (and honestly, I'm not exactly sure what it does). From what I can tell a foreign key must be equal to a primary key/unique column of a table. But what I want is all rows such that `posts.tags ~ '.*<foo>.*'`, etc. I also want to be able to, say, get all tags that start with b, eg:

```
CREATE VIEW startswithB AS
SELECT tag
FROM tags
WHERE tag ~ '<b.*>';

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM posts, startswithB WHERE posts.tags ~ ('.*' || startswithB || '.*');
```

How do I get the relation I'm looking for? Is it possible?

EDIT:

Okay, what I've done:

create post_tags:

```
SELECT posts.id, tags.tag 
INTO post_tags 
FROM posts, tags 
WHERE posts.tags ~ ('.*' || tags.tag || '.*');
```

select all posts with tag `<foo>`:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE posts.id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM post_tags
    WHERE tag = '<foo>'
);
```

Comment: Look for the sql [`LIKE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-matching.html). In your case it's not possible to create a foreign key, because the value must match in both tables.

Comment: This design is VERY bad. Are you in an environment where you can change it? An appropriate design would be : posts (id, text, stuffs) ; tags (id, tag) ; and posts_tags (post_id, tag_id) which references both the posts table and the tags table (many2many relationship: a tag has many posts and a post has many tags)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you actually have going on here is a many-to-many relationship. Think about it: each tag can be on several posts, and each post can have several tags.

The correct relational architecture for this is to add another table in the middle like this:

```
CREATE TABLE post_tags (
  id INTEGER REFERENCES posts,
  tag VARCHAR REFERENCES tags
);
```

Then drop the `tags` column on your posts table.

This solves all your issues, because you can get the set of tags on a post or the set of posts with a given tag by joining against post_tags in different directions. You can also get the list of tags that start with something using a regular LIKE query, which will be more difficult if you have a bunch of strings concatenated in one field.

Answer (score 5):

As Daniel mentioned, you have a many-to-many relationship.  Just for clarification, here's how all 3 tables would look with a many-to-many setup:

Posts:

```
    id | ... other stuff ...
    ---+---------------------
    1  | ...
    2  | ...
```

Tags:

```
    tag
    ---
    <foo>
    <bar>
```

Post_Tags mapping table:

```
    post_id | tag
    --------+------
    1       | <foo>
    1       | <bar>
```

Comment: Is post_id a primary key? If so, how can you have duplicate `1` since primary keys are `UNIQUE NOT NULL`?

Comment: @dman On mapping tables such as Post_Tags you would not normally set a primary key.

Answer (score 4):

Normalize your data model. Here is one way to represent the M:N relationship that you have:

[image]

Please note that POST_TAG's PK is {POST_ID, TAG}, not just {POST_ID}.

Finding all posts tagged with 'foo' would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM POST
WHERE
    POST_ID IN (
        SELECT POST_ID
        FROM POST_TAG
        WHERE TAG = 'foo'
    )
```

For posts tagged with a tag that starts with 'f', you could do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM POST
WHERE
    POST_ID IN (
        SELECT POST_ID
        FROM POST_TAG
        WHERE TAG LIKE 'f%'
    )
```