# creating objects instances from a related object instance based on grouping of 1 or more related object attribute

Tags: python, django

I have objects cart and cartitem with 1:N relationship.
I have objects po and poitem with 1:N relationship.
Once I've created cart and cartitem object I want to group the cartitems by a attribute of cartitem and then instance multiple po and poitem objects. Any idea how I can go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what database are you using ?

Comment: i am using postgresql.

Comment: how do you plan to group instance of multiple po and poitem objects ? Also checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606843/one-to-many-relationships-in-postgresql

Comment: My cartitems have a delivery_date field. I want to put all cartitems with the same delivery_date to one po with the every cart item coming in a one po item.

Comment: so let's say I have a cart c1, with cart items ci1, ci2, ci3 with deliveray_dates d1, d1, d2 respectively. I want to create 2 pos like so: po1 with poi1, poi2 and po2 with poi3.

Comment: The type of relationship between 1 po and cartitems ( all cartitems with the same delivery_date) would be one to many.

Comment: i don't think a many-to-many model is what I want to go with.

Comment: correct. But instead of cartitems I was thinking of going with poitems. But now that you point it out I don't see why I can't resuse cartitems itself.

Comment: So now the model should be: cart and cartitem with 1:N relationship , cartitem and po 1:1 relationship, since for every cartitem you want to associate po.

Comment: did my answer help you ? or you need more clarification ?

Comment: Going back I need to create po items for cart items because 1 cart can result in multiple pos. also the attributes of cartitem when moving a cartitem into a po may also change. my issue is not so much the data model but rather how to achieve it with django.

Comment: In the models.py write function describing the cart structure. Pass this cart structure to cartitems and po. When you'll write the structure for cartitems and po items, they would inherit cart structure, which would help you in ur 1:N relationship model.